# react router cannot access child url from browser

Tags: reactjs, react-router

Here is my redux route:

```js
const routes =  (
    <Router history={browserHistory}>
        <Route path="/" component={App}>
        <IndexRoute component={Login} />
        <Route name="first" path="/first" component={First} />
        <Route name="second" path="/second" component={Second} />
        </Route>
  </Router>
)

export default routes
```

My `App` component have `Header` and that is :

```js
class Header extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <h3><Link to="first">First</Link></h3>
        <h3><Link to="second">Second</Link></h3>
      </div>
    )
  }
}

export default Header
```

This all works fine.. My `Header` is rendered well and when I click they are routed to thier respective url..

What I am facing problem is I can only route on click.. When I access `/first` url from browser I am getting `404`.

When I access `/` it redirects me to login page with header and on clicking to the header I can route but when I directly call `/first` from browser it is giving me 404 error .

Why this ??

Would be glad if anyone answers this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to configure your server to return your application on any path that hits it. For this you can use the catch all pattern `*`.

So from within your server (assuming a Node.js server)

```
app.get('*', function (req, res) {
    res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname + '/index.html'));
});
```

and then kick off your router on the client side.

Comment: It means whatever url is hit like `/first` it should be redirected to "/" ??

Comment: If you want to use redirects, yes, else it means that the server should intercept any GET request and always serve the index.html file with your application in it.

Comment: Lets say after login I want to redirect to profile.. how to do this ?? after login I dont want to redirect to home page.. I want it to redirect to profile.. isnt it the way of doing ??

Comment: If you want to redirect from within the application use `router.transitionTo`, it's available on the context: `this.context.router.transitionTo('/login')`.

Comment: but what I want is if I load `mydomain.com/profile` profile should be displayed.. How can I do this ?? except `/` all urls are giving 404 from browser..

Comment: And my answer shows how to. You need your _server_ to serve your application on any path.

Comment: I can not get `this.context.router.transitionTo('/login')` .. it gives me `can not get context of undefined`

Comment: Define `contextTypes` in your component.